# adding multiple packages to the project

Tags: meteor

How can I add multiple packages to my project via command line? I understand I can do that via a batch script, but adding to .bat file only executes the first line, then exits.
E.g. run.bat:

> meteor add mquandalle:stylus
>   meteor add coffeescript
>   meteor add mquandalle:jade
>   meteor add dburles:lazy

adds only the first package to the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NPM style:

`meteor add mquandalle:stylus coffeescript mquandalle:jade dburles:lazy`